# Salesforce Mobile App: LWC Navigation to Standard New Record Page Errors when State Includes defaultFieldValues

Tags: lightning-web-components, navigationmixin.navigate, salesforce-mobile-app

From a browser client, navigation works as expected.  From the Salesforce mobile app, the following basic code throws an error and does not navigate.

> Error message: 'Looks like there's a problem...Error ID: 473660849-168132 (-407557566)

```
const defaultValues = encodeDefaultFieldValues({
    Subject: 'Address Change'
});

this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
    type: 'standard__objectPage',
    attributes: {
        objectApiName: 'Case',
        actionName: 'new'
    },
    state: {
        nooverride: '1',
        recordTypeId: '0122E000000yVWYQA2',
        defaultFieldValues: defaultValues
    }
});
```

The following, however, DOES work as expected:

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
    type: 'standard__objectPage',
    attributes: {
        objectApiName: 'Case',
        actionName: 'new'
    },
    state: {
        nooverride: '1',
        recordTypeId: '0122E000000yVWYQA2'        
    }
});
```

So the addition of `defaultFieldValues` seems to break mobile navigation.  Again, from a browser this all works fine.  Has anyone else seen this behavior before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`defaultFieldValues` is not supported on mobile even though `NavigateMixin` is.

[Launching Record Create Page with Default Field Values](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.links_useful_custom_buttons_create_record_dfv.htm&type=5), even though in the context of links/URLs, notes this:

> Construct custom buttons and links that **pass default field values** to a
> record create page. This feature applies to Lightning Experience in
> all editions. **This feature doesn’t apply to** Lightning Out, Experience
> Builder sites, or **the Salesforce mobile app**